# Read the last line of file with data in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file to parse in Perl. I parse it from the start of file and get the data that is needed.

After all that is done I want to read the last line in the file with data. The problem is that the last two lines are blank. So how do I get the last line that holds any data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the file is relatively short, just read on from where you finished getting the data, keeping the last non-blank line:

```
use autodie ':io';
open(my $fh, '<', 'file_to_read.txt');
# get the data that is needed, then:
my $last_non_blank_line;
while (my $line = readline $fh) {
    # choose one of the following two lines, depending what you meant
    if ( $line =~ /\S/ ) { $last_non_blank_line = $line }  # line isn't all whitespace
    # if ( line !~ /^$/ ) { $last_non_blank_line = $line } # line has no characters before the newline
}
```

If the file is longer, or you may have passed the last non-blank line in your initial data gathering step, reopen it and read from the end:

```
my $backwards = File::ReadBackwards->new( 'file_to_read.txt' );
my $last_non_blank_line;
do {
    $last_non_blank_line = $backwards->readline;
} until ! defined $last_non_blank_line || $last_non_blank_line =~ /\S/;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { if ($_) {$last = $_;} } print $last;' < my_file.txt
```

Comment: Even a blank line contains a non-empty string, namely `\n`. You want `if (/\S/)` or similar.

Comment: And if you want to keep lines with blanks, but skip lines without characters, you could use `while (<>) { chomp; if (length) { ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the module [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-ReadBackwards-1.05/ReadBackwards.pm) in the following way:

```
use File::ReadBackwards ;
$bw = File::ReadBackwards->new('filepath') or
    die "can't read file";
while( defined( $log_line = $bw->readline ) ) {
    print $log_line ;
    exit 0;
}
```

If they're blank, just check `$log_line` for a match with `\n`;

Answer (score 0):

If the file is small, I would store it in an array and read from the end. If its large, use  File::ReadBackwards module.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variant of command line perl solution:

```perl
perl -ne 'END {print $last} $last= $_ if /\S/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned `Path::Tiny`. If the file size is relativity small you can do this:

```perl
use Path::Tiny;

my $file = path($file_name);
my ($last_line) = $file->lines({count => -1});
```

[CPAN page](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#lines,-lines_raw,-lines_utf8).

Just remember for the large file, just as @ysth said it's better to use `File::ReadBackwards`. The difference can be substantial.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is more comfortable for me to run shell commands from perl code. so I'd prefer following code to resolve the case:

$result=`tail -n 1 /path/file`;